# Set QLineEdit to accept only numbers

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I have a `QLineEdit` where the user should input only numbers.

So is there a numbers-only setting for `QLineEdit`?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

`QLineEdit::setValidator()`, for example:

```
myLineEdit->setValidator( new QIntValidator(0, 100, this) );
```

or

```
myLineEdit->setValidator( new QDoubleValidator(0, 100, 2, this) );
```

See: [QIntValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qintvalidator.html), [QDoubleValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html), [QLineEdit::setValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#setValidator)

Comment: Can this be done from Qt Designer, or is it possible only through code?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to do this in designer.

Comment: This is a quick solution if you need input given in scientific notation (e.g., `3.14e-7`). `QDoubleSpinBox` does not not accept numbers in scientific notation (Qt 5.5).

Comment: If i put (1,100), it will still accept 0 as an input. Besides, I can write 0 indefinitely (not just three times) !!

Comment: See also [QRegExpValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexpvalidator.html) with QRegExp("[0-9]*").

Comment: Still works like a champ in 2020 =)  Don't forget to add the include `<QIntValidator>`.

Comment: sorry for dumb question, but how memory of this validator will be released? Is it done by qt?

Comment: @Chris `QDoubleValidator` works perfectly when you don't know how big is the integer, it stops only when you input second decimal.

Answer (score 28):

The best is [`QSpinBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html).

And for a double value use [`QDoubleSpinBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdoublespinbox.html).

```
QSpinBox myInt;
myInt.setMinimum(-5);
myInt.setMaximum(5);
myInt.setSingleStep(1);// Will increment the current value with 1 (if you use up arrow key) (if you use down arrow key => -1)
myInt.setValue(2);// Default/begining value
myInt.value();// Get the current value
//connect(&myInt, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(myValueChanged(int)));
```

Comment: Even if the OP wants to work with a QLineEdit, using a QSpinBox is definitely the best approach.

Comment: This works when the number range is small. Think about that you might want to use this widget for ages or id.

Comment: any way to make the spinbox more keyboard friendly to work with only number keys, decimal separator and backspace?

Answer (score 20):

**The Regex Validator**

So far, the other answers provide solutions for only a relatively *finite* number of digits. However, if you're concerned with an *arbitrary* or a *variable* number of digits you can use a [`QRegExpValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexpvalidator.html), passing a regex that only accepts digits (as noted by [user2962533's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422995/set-qlineedit-to-accept-only-numbers#comment63124415_13423244)). Here's a minimal, complete example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QRegExpValidator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QLineEdit le;
    le.setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[0-9]*"), &le));
    le.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The `QRegExpValidator` has its merits (and that's only an understatement). It allows for a bunch of other useful validations:

```
QRegExp("[1-9][0-9]*")    //  leading digit must be 1 to 9 (prevents leading zeroes).
QRegExp("\\d*")           //  allows matching for unicode digits (e.g. for 
                          //    Arabic-Indic numerals such as ٤٥٦).
QRegExp("[0-9]+")         //  input must have at least 1 digit.
QRegExp("[0-9]{8,32}")    //  input must be between 8 to 32 digits (e.g. for some basic
                          //    password/special-code checks).
QRegExp("[0-1]{,4}")      //  matches at most four 0s and 1s.
QRegExp("0x[0-9a-fA-F]")  //  matches a hexadecimal number with one hex digit.
QRegExp("[0-9]{13}")      //  matches exactly 13 digits (e.g. perhaps for ISBN?).
QRegExp("[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}")
                          //  matches a format similar to an ip address.
                          //    N.B. invalid addresses can still be entered: "999.999.999.999".
```

**More On Line-edit Behaviour**

According to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#details):

> Note that if there is a validator set on the line edit, the returnPressed()/editingFinished() signals will only be emitted if the validator returns QValidator::Acceptable.

Thus, the line-edit will allow the user to input digits even if the minimum amount has not yet been reached. For example, even if the user hasn't inputted any text against the regex `"[0-9]{3,}"` (which requires at least 3 digits), the line-edit still allows the user to type input to *reach* that minimum requirement. However, if the user finishes editing without satsifying the requirement of "at least 3 digits", the input would be *invalid*; the signals `returnPressed()` and `editingFinished()` won't be emitted.

If the regex had a maximum-bound (e.g. `"[0-1]{,4}"`), then the line-edit will stop any input past 4 characters. Additionally, for character sets (i.e. `[0-9]`, `[0-1]`, `[0-9A-F]`, etc.) the line-edit only allows characters from *that particular set* to be inputted.

*<sub>Note that I've only tested this with Qt 5.11 on a macOS, not on other Qt versions or operating systems. But given Qt's cross-platform schema...</sub>*

***<sub>Demo: [Regex Validators Showcase](https://github.com/TrebledJ/Qt-Examples/tree/master/%5Bwidgets%5D--regex-validators)</sub>***

Answer (score 10):

You could also set an [`inputMask`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop):

```py
QLineEdit.setInputMask("9")
```

This allows the user to type only one digit ranging from `0` to `9`. Use multiple `9`'s to allow the user to enter multiple numbers. See also the complete [list of characters that can be used in an input mask](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop).

(My answer is in Python, but it should not be hard to transform it to C++)

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you use a `QSpinBox` for this purpose ? You can set the up/down buttons invisible with the following line of codes:

```
// ...
QSpinBox* spinBox = new QSpinBox( this );
spinBox->setButtonSymbols( QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons ); // After this it looks just like a QLineEdit.
//...
```

Comment: Note that NoButons doesn't actually remove the buttons, it just makes them the same color as the background of the QSpinBox. So in certain styles where the arrows are large, you'll have an annoyingly larger part of the QSpinBox that just looks blank and squishes the rest of the input field

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Qt 5.6, you can do that like this:

```cpp
#include <QIntValidator>

ui->myLineEditName->setValidator( new QIntValidator);
```

I recommend you put that line after `ui->setupUi(this);`.

Comment: Your constructor invocation should be `new QIntValidator(this)`, otherwise the validator object will leak as soon as your widget goes out of scope.