# Qt Plain text edit, printing from right

Tags: qt, calculator, plaintext

I am making a calculator in qt. 
I have  a plain text edit box. 
when I input numbers in it, I want it to print from the right(like any other calculator).

also, I want to disable input of anything except numbers. 
(little new in qt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight)` of your QLineEdit and

`QLineEdit::setValidator()`, for example:

```
myLineEdit->setValidator( new QIntValidator(0, 100, this) );
```

Take alook at this one as well: [Set QLineEdit to accept only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422995/set-qlineedit-to-accept-only-numbers)